# How do I fix the "Incorrect Resource URL" alert?

Tags: resource-urls

I've just a done a clean install by the book of CiviCRM 5.24 on Drupal 7. The installation went smoothly. Now I'm seeing an alert about the Resource URL being incorrect (it isn't). I seem to recall that this was an issue a year or so ago. Is this a regression that has crept in to the latest version, or am I doing something wrong? I have other D7/Civi installs on the same server, all with earlier versions of CiviCRM, and none of them are exhibiting this behaviour.

Comment: Are you using a self-signed ssl certificate?

Comment: LetsEncrypt certificate

Comment: Ok then here's a couple things to try: 1. Can the server itself look up the domain name, e.g. using command line nslookup or dig? 2. Put some debugging just after [line 867](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.24.1/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Env.php#L867) in CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Env.php to verify what url it's trying to fetch, e.g. add `CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message($arrowUrl);` and then look in ConfigAndLog.

Comment: Looks like there might be an issue with the DNS servers that my server is using by default to look up the domain. It appears that my domain's records have not propagated to these servers, although I can reach the domain from elsewhere. Talking to my hosting provider...

Answer (score 1):

The Resource URL lookup uses the PHP setting curl.cainfo to look up a certificate file, e.g. CACert.pem to validate the server certificate.  I found the problem went away when I added the server certificate to that file.

See [Installing drupal 8 using civicrm-setup leads to "incorrect resource url" system status check errors](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/114#note_34273)